# Groupby and reduce pandas dataframes with numpy arrays as entries

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, reduce

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with the following structure:

```
>>> data 
a    b    values
1    0    [1, 2, 3, 4]
2    0    [3, 4, 5, 6]
1    1    [1, 3, 7, 9]
2    1    [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

(`'values'` has the type of `numpy.array`). What I want to do is to group the data by column `'a'` and then combine the list of values.
My goal is to end up with the following:

```
>>> data 
a    values
1    [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 7, 9]
2    [3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Note, that the order of the values **does not** matter. How do I achieve this? I though about something like

```
>>> grps = data.groupby(['a'])
>>> grps['values'].agg(np.concatenate)
```

but this fails with a `KeyError`. I'm sure there is a pandaic way to achieve this - but how?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to the John Galt's answer, you can group and then apply `np.hstack`:

```
In [278]: df.groupby('a')['values'].apply(np.hstack)
Out[278]: 
a
1    [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 7, 9]
2    [3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 6, 8]
Name: values, dtype: object
```

To get back your frame, you'll need `pd.Series.to_frame` and `pd.reset_index`:

```
In [311]: df.groupby('a')['values'].apply(np.hstack).to_frame().reset_index()
Out[311]: 
   a                    values
0  1  [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 7, 9]
1  2  [3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

---

**Performance**

```
df_test = pd.concat([df] * 10000) # setup

%timeit df_test.groupby('a')['values'].apply(np.hstack) # mine
1 loop, best of 3: 219 ms per loop

%timeit df_test.groupby('a')['values'].sum() # John's 
1 loop, best of 3: 4.44 s per loop
```

`sum` is very inefficient for list, and does not work when `Values` is a `np.array`.

Comment: How do I achieve, that the resulting column still has the name `'values'`?

Comment: @rammelmuller What do you want to do about a, and b? Drop it?

Comment: `'b'` is dropped by default, `'a'` should stay and be called the same.

Comment: @rammelmuller There you go, enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sum` to join lists.

```
In [640]: data.groupby('a')['values'].sum()
Out[640]:
a
1    [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 7, 9]
2    [3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 6, 8]
Name: values, dtype: object
```

Or,

```
In [653]: data.groupby('a', as_index=False).agg({'values': 'sum'})
Out[653]:
   a                    values
0  1  [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 7, 9]
1  2  [3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: It seems, that with numpy arrays the sum version does not work, it fails with the message: 'function does not reduce' - I edited the numpy array detail a little too lat, sorry.